# SCNAction playAudio seems to cause a crash

Tags: ios, swift, audio, scenekit

I am seeing a crash in SceneKit that I was not seeing before iOS 13.1.2.

I’ve traced the issue to the following function and cannot completely suss out what is causing the issue.

If I comment out the line which runs the action on the node, all is well.

I can run playAudio actions on other pre-existing nodes in the scene but when I simply want to have a one-shot sound play using the below function, the app crashes.

So my thought is that perhaps this has something to do with the way I am instantiating the node but I cannot think of another way to instantiate a node just to play a sound at a given position.

I’ve also tried using a recycled audio source but that makes no difference.

Might anyone have any ideas what might be going on in this code to cause a crash? It’s just not obvious to me, especially since this had worked flawlessly before the iOS updates.

I’ve included the back trace below.

Thanks so much for any help / ideas!

Have a great weekend!

Cheers!

```
func play(sound: String, atPosition: SCNVector3, volume: Float, pitch: Float, loops: Bool, positional: Bool) {

// Sources will be pre-loaded and recycled for the finished app

if let source = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/"+sound)
{
source.volume = volume
source.rate = pitch
source.isPositional = positional
source.shouldStream = false
source.loops = loops
source.load()

let node = SCNNode()

node.name = "oneShot"

node.position = atPosition

scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

// node.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.playAudio(source, waitForCompletion: true), SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()]))

// This line causes the crash

node.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(source, waitForCompletion: false))

}

}
```

- thread #14, name = 'com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer', queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.SCNView0x105a11e90', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x830b67ea0)

  - frame #0: 0x00000001b08d7030 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 16
    frame #1: 0x00000001bd5a90c4 AVFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayerNode didAttachToEngine:] + 140
    frame #2: 0x00000001bd5b66e8 AVFAudio`AVAudioEngineImpl::AttachNode(AVAudioNode*, bool) + 272
    frame #3: 0x00000001bd5b2324 AVFAudio`-[AVAudioEngine attachNode:] + 80
    frame #4: 0x00000001c4aea48c SceneKit`CPP3DAudioContext::AddVoice(void const*) + 120
    frame #5: 0x00000001c4aeacf0 SceneKit`CPP3DAudioEngine::AddVoice(void const*) + 192
    frame #6: 0x00000001c49bd618 SceneKit`C3DNodeAddAudioPlayer + 40
    frame #7: 0x00000001c4a07924 SceneKit`-[SCNNode addAudioPlayer:] + 132
    frame #8: 0x00000001c49325e0 SceneKit`SCNCPlaySound::cpp_updateWithTargetForTime(SCNNode*, double) + 96
    frame #9: 0x00000001c499c690 SceneKit`SCNActionApply + 112
    frame #10: 0x00000001c4a2d7a4 SceneKit`_applyActions + 236
    frame #11: 0x00000001b0a8e1b8 CoreFoundation`-[**NSFrozenDictionaryM __apply:context:] + 128
    frame #12: 0x00000001c4a2d5c8 SceneKit`C3DAnimationManagerApplyActions + 104
    frame #13: 0x00000001c4a173e4 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _update:] + 576
    frame #14: 0x00000001c4a19a04 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawSceneWithNewRenderer:] + 200
    frame #15: 0x00000001c4a19fbc SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawScene:] + 48
    frame #16: 0x00000001c4a1a350 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawAtTime:] + 616
    frame #17: 0x00000001c4ab46b8 SceneKit`-[SCNView _drawAtTime:] + 428
    frame #18: 0x00000001c497ae38 SceneKit`__69-[NSObject(SCN_DisplayLinkExtensions) SCN_setupDisplayLinkWithQueue:]_block_invoke + 56
    frame #19: 0x00000001c4a7fe48 SceneKit`__36-[SCNDisplayLink _callbackWithTime:]_block_invoke + 64
    frame #20: 0x0000000105726c04 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #21: 0x0000000105735888 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 124
    frame #22: 0x00000001c4a7fdd8 SceneKit`-[SCNDisplayLink _callbackWithTime:] + 232
    frame #23: 0x00000001058f95f8 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 168
    frame #24: 0x00000001b73da514 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 632
    frame #25: 0x00000001b1acdeb0 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 488
    frame #26: 0x00000001b0ae96d4 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 172
    frame #27: 0x00000001b0b12e5c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 56
    frame #28: 0x00000001b0b12588 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
    frame #29: 0x00000001b0b0d45c CoreFoundation`**CFRunLoopRun + 2168
    frame #30: 0x00000001b0b0c8bc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    frame #31: 0x00000001b0e4c994 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
    frame #32: 0x00000001c497b214 SceneKit`__71-[SCNView(SCNDisplayLink) _initializeDisplayLinkWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 456
    frame #33: 0x00000001c497b45c SceneKit`__SCNRenderThread_start** + 96
    frame #34: 0x00000001b08b11ec libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 124

Comment: To the person who down-voted this, please consider posting a comment with feedback? -Otherwise I cannot improve the question. If I felt that the question was lacking in some way, according to my understanding of the Stack guidelines and other questions I've read here, I would not have posted. So if you wouldn't mind elaborating on your down-vote, it would certainly be a lot more helpful. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wanted to update my question to say that this issue has resolved itself after updating to iOS 13.2. -My thanks to Apple. :)